# update columns using select statement

Tags: sql, select, firebird

I want to update columns based on result of select statement you find my query below ,my code doesn't work correctly :
I get the same  data on all my columns

```
update ACHATS  b set 
QUANTITE=(select sum(QUANTITE)     from ACHAT_DETAILS a where a.NUMERO_D_ACHAT=(SELECT max(ID_ACHAT) M_ID_ACHAT from ACHATS) 
group by a.NUMERO_D_ACHAT) ,
PRIX_HT=(select sum(PRIX_HT)       from ACHAT_DETAILS a where a.NUMERO_D_ACHAT=(SELECT max(ID_ACHAT) M_ID_ACHAT from ACHATS) 
group by a.NUMERO_D_ACHAT),
PRIX_TTC=(select sum(PRIX_HT) from ACHAT_DETAILS a where a.NUMERO_D_ACHAT=(SELECT max(ID_ACHAT) M_ID_ACHAT from ACHATS) 
group by a.NUMERO_D_ACHAT);
```

Comment: Please give additional details to "doesn't work correctly".  Are you getting an error?  What is the output?  What is wrong with it?  What is the desired output?

Comment: no error but all the results are same

Comment: Sorry, but "results are same" is not informative.  Perhaps read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Where is this code? In a script, stored procedure or ...? I don't see `commit` Please read [mcve]

Comment: Do not give us your code to debug. Start with giving the sample source data, the result you want to get, and the HUMAN-READABLE description of your intention, of why you want your data processed that way. I can not read your memories and thoughts when I look at your code, which is probably anyway not working as you wanted it.

Comment: You should look at [`MERGE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-dml-merge.html)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel there would be another issue - to create reference SELECT to merge with.... Perhaps using other tricks like GTT or pseudo-table via `SELECT const-vector FROM RDB$DATABASE UNION ALL SELECT const-vector....`

Comment: @Arioch'The Unclear what you mean, this question is phrased poorly, but probably the merge can be very simple without resorting to that sort of trickery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct update query for the question is:

```
update ACHATS b set 
  QUANTITE = (select sum(QUANTITE)
                from ACHAT_DETAILS a 
                where a.NUMERO_D_ACHAT = (
                  select max(ID_ACHAT)
                    from ACHATS)
             ),
  PRIX_HT = (select sum(PRIX_HT)
               from ACHAT_DETAILS a 
               where a.NUMERO_D_ACHAT = (
                 select max(ID_ACHAT)  
                   from ACHATS)
            ),
  PRIX_TTC = (select sum(PRIX_HT)  
                from ACHAT_DETAILS a 
                where a.NUMERO_D_ACHAT = (
                  select max(ID_ACHAT)
                  from ACHATS)
             )
  where b.ID_ACHAT = (select max(ID_ACHAT)
                        from ACHATS)
```

Answer (score 0):

So to test this out try the below code to see if that is the results you were expecting to use to update your table first:

```
   WITH B AS (
    SELECT  MAX(M_ID_ACHAT) AS NUMERO_D_ACHAT
          , SUM(QUANTITE) AS QUANTITE
          , SUM(PRIX_HT) AS PRIX_HT
          , SUM(PRIX_TTC) AS PRIX_TTC
    FROM    ACHAT_DETAILS
    GROUP BY 
        MAX(M_ID_ACHAT)
    )


SELECT
    b.QUANTITE
    ,b.PRIX_HT
    ,b.PRIX_TTC
FROM ACHAT_DETAILS a
JOIN  b
    ON a.NUMERO_D_ACHAT = b.NUMERO_D_ACHAT
```

Next if that all looks good then you can run this (I think I got the syntax correct):

```
WITH A AS (
SELECT  MAX(M_ID_ACHAT) AS NUMERO_D_ACHAT
      , SUM(QUANTITE) AS QUANTITE
      , SUM(PRIX_HT) AS PRIX_HT
      , SUM(PRIX_TTC) AS PRIX_TTC
FROM    ACHAT_DETAILS
GROUP BY 
    MAX(M_ID_ACHAT)
)


MERGE INTO ACHATS AS u
    USING A
    ON u.NUMERO_D_ACHAT = a.NUMERO_D_ACHAT
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE 
            SET 
             u.QUANTITE = a.QUANTITE
            ,u.PRIX_HT = a.PRIX_HT
            ,u.PRIX_TTC = a.PRIX_TTC
```

Comment: Syntax is not correct. `UPDATE ... SET ... FROM ...` - there is not FROM clause in UPDATE statements. http://firebirdsql.su/doku.php?id=update Perhaps what you wanted to use was MERGE instead. http://firebirdsql.su/doku.php?id=merge

Comment: Hi Arioch....this actually does run, I ran a test :-)   This way you can filter your results or update using a join

Comment: full query, firebird version and screenshot, if you please: I am sure your second sources text is not complete and is not EXACTLY matching what you really is running. Or you test with some other RDBMS not firebird

Comment: thanks for reply  for the first code he gave the correct data but the second code didn’t work on firebird give error :
Token unknown - line 5, column 1.
FROM.
SQL Error (code = -104):
Invalid token.

Comment: I tried it, but he didn't work (I'm working under Firebird database)

Comment: OK sorry bout that

Comment: don't worry thx for the help anyway I need you in the future :)

Comment: @RyanDavidHocking  WITH ... MERGE - there is no that syntax. I guess one can try luck with derived tables like `MERGE ...  USING ( SELECT .....FROM .... ) AS A ....` - and that is exactly how it used in the example statement at the link I gave in the first comment :-D

Comment: Is a derived table in firebird like a CTE or temp table or like a view?

Comment: What's the difference you mean? I can only see that recursive (and only recursive) CTEs would get re-evaluated for every new row, and then view and non-recursive CTEs are only evaluated (instantiated as data streams) once. So, I can not see the difference you ask about.  PS. a very theoretical 2006 article from the core developer: www.translate.ru -> http://www.ibase.ru/dataaccesspaths/  Anyway the topicstarter can run the query on real DB, then read the query `PLAN` to see how server did it and what scaling to expect

Comment: Also, temp tables in MS SQL and FB SQL are rather different beasts: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/global-temp-tables/info